# Magento 2.3 File validation failed when uploading SVG image in CMS

Tags: cms, magento2.3, svg

I created a module, to override `vendor/magento/module-cms/etc/di.xml`, since SVG format is not supported by default

This is how di.xml looks like in my module.

```
<type name="Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Images\Storage">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="extensions" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="allowed" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="svg" xsi:type="string">image/svg</item>
            </item>
            <item name="image_allowed" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="svg" xsi:type="string">image/svg</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

But I'm still not able to upload SVG files.

It gives me "File validation failed",

[image]

What else should I do to be able to upload SVG format?

I'm using Magento 2.3.11

Comment: Try this  <item name="svg" xsi:type="string">image/svg+xml</item>

Comment: @magento Learner are you found any solution?

Comment: @SavanPatel unfortunatly no.